# mail() PHP insertion in $_POST causing connection timeout

Tags: php, forms, post, server, connection-timeout

When I try to visit our website on our server my pc (and my pc alone) gets a time out error when trying to visit any part of the site.

This is how I caused the problem, I inserted:

```
?>
< ?php 
$to = 'myemail'; 
$subject = 'test'; 
$text = 'test2'; 
$header = 'test3'; 
mail($to,$subject,$text,$header); ?>
< ?php
```

(without the spaces behind the < ).

In `$_POST['var2']` field on my websites form to test the difference between `strip_tags($_POST[''])` and regular unprotected `$_POST['']`.

That `$_POST['']` field together with a couple more feed into a `$url` variable below:

```
$url = 'ourwebsite/filecontainingthis$urlvariable.php?VAR1='.strip_tags($_POST['var1'].'&VAR2='.$_POST['var2'].'&VAR3='.strip_tags($_POST['var3']);
```

(Where myemail was my actual functioning email adress and ourwebsite is the actual adres of our website)

I have done the following to try and remove the problem:

- Cleared all cookies and history from my browser
- Used another browser
- Rebooted pc
- Given it a day to see if the request gets automatically removed by the server

How can I regain access to the website on this pc/stop that broken request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that doing this causes your host to flag you as a malicious/spam e-mail sender. Your options are to contact your host to get the block lifted or wait out the quarantine period if applicable.